# How to run HttpListener from a thread when a WebAPI (aspx project) program starts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a tool for the QA team.

One of the features I'd like to add is a webhook for some events (sent as JSONs when some actions are taken).

AFAIK, in C# .NET Core v2.2, this feature is mostly implemented using the HttpListener class.

What I'd like to do is to run my simple Listener class/function in a parallel thread to the main program so events can be processed while the rest of the solution is active (it serves as an API to query DB).

My question is how to implement this.

**my question mainly focus on how to run the listener on a background thread during app start - not on implementation of the connection.**

The "Startup" is where I'd try to add it but I'm not sure how.

I found the services part (AddService, AddSingleton...) But couldn't find anything specific. Am I on the right track?

I didn't paste any code as the implementation is irrelevant (I guess) but will upload the Listener should anyone ask.

Comment: If you want to start Listener somewhere,you only need to use `SimpleListenerExample(xxxx);`And here is [an official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-5.0) to write a HttpListener.

Comment: The question does not focus on using HttpListener. That i can find plenty. Question is how to use it on a background thread when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Is this existing in a Web app, or a Console App?

You might have a much easier time piggybacking on SignalR if you want to send Server->Client style events in json

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Pretty easy to setup and get running, you can have clients subscribe to listen to an API end point and then bind to events to fire off functions when they get pinged from the server.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comment! My question focuses on how to use it during app start as a background thread. implementation should b easier - although this lib defiantly calls for usage! any ideas? thanks!

Comment: I think its 99% based on what the consumer of your webhook "events" looks like. Is a web UI that you can just feed these events out into plenty acceptable?

If so, SignalR seems fine, just implement an injected service that fires off the SignalR events to listeners by injecting the Hub wrapper into that service, and then inject your "EventService" you have made into your classes that trigger the events.

Comment: Here's an example of me doing it on my project

Event firing: https://github.com/SteffenBlake/TaskBud/blob/master/Source/TaskBud.Business/Services/Implementations/TaskManager.cs#L51

And the event service:
https://github.com/SteffenBlake/TaskBud/blob/master/Source/TaskBud.Website/Services/TaskEventHandler.cs

And consuming it:
https://github.com/SteffenBlake/TaskBud/blob/master/Source/TaskBud.Website/Views/Tasks/Index.cshtml#L25-L40

And registering:
https://github.com/SteffenBlake/TaskBud/blob/master/Source/TaskBud.Website/Startup.cs#L169-L170

Easy peasy!